# Can Arduino be used as an FDTI Programmer?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, ftdi

I would like to program my ESP 8266 WiFi module. But I don't have an FDTI right now is there any way to use Arduino Uno as FDTI Programmer then use ESP without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Tie the reset pin on the ISP connector low to keep the ATmega328P in reset, then you can connect pins 0 and 1 to the ESP module to communicate using the Uno's USB-UART bridge. Since the pins are labelled from the perspective of the '328P, connect TX to TX and RX to RX.